# Mule:Setting Rest Call response as property in original message payload

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Having a scenario where consuming a message from amqp:inboundendpoint and then requesting a call to rest service using HTTP outbound endpoint with request response message exchange pattern. I need to set properties of message payload received from amqp with certain data retrieved in HTTP outbound response. What is the best component to acheive this design. Do i need to call HTTP outbound inside an enricher and then enrich the payload with additional properties retrieved from rest call or is there any other design possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message enritcher was designed exactly for this scenario please take a look a [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Victor said, Mule Message Enricher will be a good option to be used in this kind of scenario..

What message enricher actually does is it enrich an incoming message with additional information (That's what your need ) and perform a particular task without disturbing or modifying the original payload...

So in that case, the message processor after enricher will be getting the original payload without being modified... So I can say, your approach is correct  and you can go with enricher..
you can find more about enricher :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher
and 
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/enrich-your-experience-orchestration-and-data-enrichment-with-mule-3-1/